# How to add an image for an accessoryCorner in Widget extension for watchOS 10?

Tags: swiftui, watchos, widgetkit

This is the code I am trying to display for my `.accessoryCorner`:

```
if #available(watchOS 10.0, *) {
    Image.briefcase
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        .widgetCurvesContent()
        .widgetLabel("28h 18' +15'")
        .widgetBackground(backgroundColor)
        .widgetURL(URL(string: "widget-currentmonth://?action=currentmonth"))
}
```

where

```
extension Image {
    static var briefcase: Image {
        Image(systemName: "briefcase.fill")
    }
}
```

and the effect is the following:

[image]

Linear version look like this. I need here the same info, with the same icon;)

[image]

Simply, it doesn't work. I need there my image to indicate what that means. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is very simple:

```
Text(Image.briefcase)
    .font(.system(size: 29))
```

and the effect is like this:

[image]